# Most songs in my media collection play twice. Corrupt media?

Tags: external-hard-drive, media, media-player

Whether I'm playing the media with Rhythmbox on Ubuntu, Winamp on Windows, or my Nokia N95's media player, most of my audio files (OK, maybe only 40%) play twice.

I have a 500GB external 2.5" WD HDD, with a 150GB primary FAT32 partition labeled MUSIC.

Inside this, I have about 500 folders containing about 10,000 MP3/WMA/M4A/WAV files.

I manage the drive using Ubuntu 9.10, and frequently copy data to/from it using RSYNC, or on windows, TotalCopy.

The visual output is different in each media player, but it behaves as if the 1 MP3 has the same song on it twice, and as soon as it ends it begins again.
Winamp shows that the song goes for 2x as long as it should, The N95's media player shows the progress bar off the right-hand-side of the screen when it begins playing (then jumps back to the left, then continues along...).
Rhythmbox doesn't show me how long the song is, nor does the progress bar move along the screen.

It seams to me somewhere along the lines my collection has become corrupt. But where? And how?

Comment: Are the corrupt files twice the size they should be?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a bunch of m3u playlist files?  I had a similar issue in iTunes until I removed all my m3u's.  At least for iTunes, it treats the mp3 as one file, and then adds the mp3 to its playlist again when it finds it in an m3u.

Comment: Nope, no M3U's. :(